# BroadcastReceiver for mobile data

Tags: android

I have this BroadCastReceiver for listening to changes in the `WiFi` state:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mWifiStateChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int extraWifiState = intent.getIntExtra(
                WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN
                );

        wifiState = new WifiState(Main.this);

        switch (extraWifiState) {

        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
            wifiState.haveNetworkConnection();
            break;

        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:

            ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            while (conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null
                    || conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo().getState() != NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                wifiState.cancelDialog();

            }
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

How can I add support for listening to mobile data in this broadcastreceiver, aswell?

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for `"android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE"` and you will get notified when data connectivity state changes (mobile data and/or wifi).